# Listening to the HTML5 file system in a Chrome Application

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am working on a Google Chrome App which reads from and writes to the sandboxed local file system.

I am accessing the file system by invoking `window.webkitRequestFileSystem || window.requestFileSystem`

This is a large application, and I have some code components creating and deleting files (call them the producers), and other code components displaying the files (the consumers).

For clean separation of code, I don't want the producers and consumers to know about one another. I would like the consumers to simply watch the file system, and react appropriately when files are created or modified.

Sadly, it appears that the framework provides no way to add a listener to the local file system.

Am I correct in saying that?

Comment: You may want to change that title. Since a Chrome App can get access to the _local files_, that's what I assumed. You are talking about the HTML5 filesystem instead (not accessing the "normal" files).

Comment: @xan Thanka, I've followed your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is in the works and may land within the next few months. See [relevant issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=261491)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link. It looks like the last comment on this was made in April 2015. 
I won't be holding my breath :-)